# Session factories to handle multiple DB connections

Tags: hibernate, spring, dao, quest

I have a task to create multiple session factories for different Data Sources. One data source will be used for read requests and another for read-write requests.

Each API of our Database Service(a wrapper over DAO)  is executed as a transaction. Single API may call multiple DAO functions having different Read/Write property.

What is the best possible way to perform this task?

Comment: I think this topic will give some help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2017949/when-to-use-global-transaction-or-use-spring-aop-for-transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that the different datasources are different DBs . Else you could use the readOnly attribute with the @Transactional annotation to manage the read only transactions.

You could inject two separate session factories in the DAO layer to manage these transactions . Alternatively , you could use AbstractRoutingDataSource . See a write up on this [here](http://blog.springsource.org/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/)

Comment: Yes, different datasources are different DBs.

Comment: Then you could inject different sessionfactories . If you have different transaction managers, then you could use @Transactional("TxManagerName") . You could wire this all up with AbstractRoutingDataSource . But is you you plan to work across different transactional datasource within the same method - i.e , if one DB rollback should affect the other , consider using XA datasource .

Comment: This is really helpful. 
Could you please tell me the pros and cons of connecting to multiple DBs from a single API?
Apart from this, might be naive but what is the way to use global transaction (XA datasource) in Spring?

Comment: @tyro - Please upvote(click on the up arrow)/check the tick mark if you are happy with the answer

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation :( 
Could you please answer the previous question?

Comment: @tyro For XA datasource , you could use JTA transaction manager which supports both XA and non XA transactions .Check out [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-2007/jw-04-xa.html) link for JTA configurations .